# computing the distance between ( XYZ coordinates)

Tags: protein-structure, linux, awk

I have a txt file (50k) proteins in it, which looks like this:

line 1:the protein code

line 2: protein length in amino acids

line 3: amino acid sequence

line 4: secondary structure

line 5: XYZ coordinates(which is numbers).

line 6:embty

the input looks like this :

```
4LGTD
247
M       S       E       K       L       Q       K       V       L       A       R       A       G       H       G       S       R   T
.       .       E       E       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       T       T       S       S       .       H   .
-34.3 -28.9 16.3        -33.0 -26.8 13.4        -29.4 -25.4 13.3        -27.9 -22.6 11.2        -26.9 -24.1 7.8 -23.3 -22.9 8.2 -23.0 -24.7 11.5     -24.1 -27.9 9.9 -21.8 -27.7 6.9 -18.8 -26.7 9.0 -19.5 -29.7 11.3        -19.6 -31.9 8.2 -16.2 -30.7 7.2 -16.7 -28.2 4.4      -15.0 -25.1 5.8 -15.4 -22.7 8.7 -18.8 -21.3 9.7 -17.7 -17.9 8.3 -16.3 -19.3 5.1 -19.5 -21.2 4.5 -21.5 -18.0 5.1 -19.7 -16.2 2.3      -20.8 -19.1 -0.0        -24.4 -19.2 1.2 -24.6 -15.4 0.6 -23.5 -16.0 -3.0        -26.4 -18.4 -3.6        -24.1 -21.4 -4.0    -25.9 -23.6 -1.5 -29.3 -25.2 -2.0        -31.4 -27.0 0.5 -34.0 -29.5 -0.8        -33.9 -27.8 -4.2        -34.1 -24.2 -3.0        -31.3 -21.7 -2.9     -30.7 -21.0 0.8 -30.2 -17.5 2.2 -27.9 -16.3 4.9 -29.4 -17.1 8.3 -31.3 -20.1 7.0 -31.7 -23.1 9.4 -32.1 -26.8 8.7 -32.6 -30.1 10.5     -30.2 -32.9 9.7 -32.0 -36.0 8.4 -31.6 -38.7 5.7 -34.0 -36.6 3.6 -32.0 -33.4 3.7 -30.4 -32.7 0.4 -27.7 -30.0 0.6 -25.8 -29.0 -2.5     -23.0 -26.6 -3.0        -22.5 -25.6 -6.6        -25.0 -28.3 -7.5        -22.9 -31.1 -5.9        -24.6 -33.1 -3.2    -23.0 -33.1 0.2  -23.1 -36.0 2.6 -23.7 -34.9 6.2 -23.8 -36.9 9.4 -27.2 -37.3 11.1        -28.5 -37.1 14.7        -19.2 -38.7 17.8    -17.7 -36.6 20.6 -14.0 -37.3 20.3        -11.2 -35.4 22.0        -7.4 -35.3 21.2 -4.7 -34.3 23.6 -1.9 -32.6 21.6 1.6 -31.6 22.7  2.2 -28.4 20.7       5.8 -27.5 20.1  7.1 -23.9 19.9  7.1 -22.6 16.3  3.6 -24.0 15.4  0.7 -21.6 14.7  -2.8 -22.2 16.0 -4.8 -21.4 12.8 -6.4 -23.3 9.9       -4.8 -20.9 7.5  -1.6 -18.8 8.1  -1.1 -16.0 5.5  2.7 -16.4 6.0   3.0 -20.1 5.2   4.2 -21.3 8.7   3.5 -24.7 10.3  0.1 -24.9 11.9       -1.1 -27.3 14.7 -3.6 -28.9 12.3 -1.0 -30.0 9.8  -0.7 -33.4 11.5 -4.0 -34.7 12.9 -6.1 -37.9 12.3 -8.5 -37.7 9.3  -12.2 -38.1 10.1     -15.3 -39.0 8.2 -17.5 -36.0 7.6 -16.2 -34.0 10.6        -13.2 -31.8 11.6        -10.9 -31.0 14.5        -11.7 -27.8 16.4     -8.8 -26.3 18.5 -9.8 -25.6 22.1 -8.4 -22.1 22.1 -5.0 -20.9 20.9 -1.5 -21.1 22.2 1.2 -18.6 21.2  3.8 -19.7 18.6  6.6 -20.0 21.1       4.5 -21.3 23.9  4.7 -25.1 24.5  2.3 -27.7 25.8  -1.3 -29.0 25.9 -3.8 -28.1 23.2 -7.0 -30.0 23.1 -8.9 -30.7 19.9 -12.5 -32.0 19.6     -14.9 -32.8 16.9        -17.6 -31.5 19.2        -17.9 -27.7 18.8        -20.2 -27.3 21.8        -17.6 -29.0 24.0        -15.0 -26.8 22.4     -16.8 -23.5 23.1        -17.7 -24.6 26.6        -14.1 -25.3 27.4        -12.9 -21.9 26.0        -15.6 -19.6 27.2    -14.8 -18.2 30.6 -18.4 -18.5 31.9        -17.5 -22.1 32.5        -14.3 -21.2 34.4        -12.2 -24.1 33.1        -8.7 -24.1 34.5 -5.7 -23.6 32.3      -2.5 -24.5 34.2 0.9 -23.2 33.2  4.4 -23.9 34.3  6.1 -20.6 34.0  9.8 -20.0 34.3  10.1 -16.4 35.4 13.0 -14.0 35.5 13.3 -11.2 38.1      12.7 -10.5 41.8 9.7 -12.2 43.3  8.4 -12.0 46.8  5.2 -13.0 48.6  3.7 -9.5 48.4   3.8 -9.8 44.6   2.2 -13.2 44.8  -0.6 -11.7 47.0      -1.0 -8.9 44.5  -1.3 -11.3 41.5 -3.9 -13.4 43.4 -6.1 -10.5 44.4 -6.1 -8.6 41.1  -3.9 -6.2 39.3  -4.5 -3.7 36.4  -3.6 -4.8 32.9       -3.8 -2.6 29.8  -7.0 -4.4 29.0  -8.5 -4.4 32.5  -8.2 -6.2 35.8  -6.8 -9.7 35.9  -5.7 -12.2 38.6 -4.2 -15.6 38.7 -6.6 -18.1 40.2      -3.8 -20.0 41.8 -0.0 -19.4 42.0 2.4 -21.9 43.4  6.2 -21.7 43.7  7.6 -24.7 41.8  11.4 -24.5 42.2 14.2 -22.0 42.2 17.4 -20.5 41.0      18.6 -17.0 41.7 16.7 -14.6 39.4 15.1 -17.6 37.8 12.2 -19.4 39.4 9.4 -21.8 38.3  5.8 -21.1 39.2  2.7 -23.1 38.4  -0.3 -20.8 37.8      -3.8 -21.1 36.7 -6.3 -18.9 34.9 -9.9 -19.4 34.1 -9.9 -17.1 31.1 -7.6 -16.7 28.1 -6.8 -13.1 27.2 -4.0 -12.5 24.7 -0.6 -13.1 26.3      -2.2 -12.9 29.7 0.3 -14.9 31.8  3.2 -12.8 30.5  1.3 -9.5 31.1   0.4 -10.5 34.6  4.0 -11.2 35.6  5.1 -8.0 33.8   2.5 -6.0 35.8        4.6 -6.8 38.9   8.0 -6.3 37.2   8.8 -9.9 36.2   9.7 -11.4 32.9  8.9 -14.8 31.5  11.6 -17.1 30.0 9.5 -20.2 29.5  5.8 -21.0 29.3       4.3 -24.5 29.1  0.6 -25.3 29.3  0.5 -28.5 31.4  -3.2 -28.9 32.0 -6.5 -27.9 30.5 -9.5 -28.7 32.7 -9.1 -32.2 34.0 -6.7 -33.3 31.2      -3.0 -32.9 32.1 -0.4 -33.0 29.4 -0.1 -36.8 28.8 2.9 -38.3 30.7  4.2 -40.6 28.0  3.5 -38.2 25.2  6.4 -36.4 23.5  6.5 -32.9 22.0       4.6 -32.8 18.6  2.5 -35.9 19.2  -1.1 -36.5 20.3 -3.4 -39.1 21.9 -7.1 -39.7 22.0 -9.2 -39.8 25.2 -11.5 -42.8 25.8    -15.2 -42.7 26.7 -14.8 -42.3 30.4        -12.3 -39.5 30.0        -14.2 -37.7 27.3        -17.3 -38.0 29.6        -15.4 -36.5 32.6    -14.3 -33.6 30.4 -17.9 -33.1 29.4        -19.2 -33.2 33.0        -16.7 -30.4 33.8        -18.7 -28.1 31.6        -22.2 -29.4 32.6    -22.6 -31.6 29.5 -24.2 -35.0 30.3        -22.3 -38.2 29.6        -22.5 -39.9 26.3        -22.8 -43.7 25.4

1XXIJ
334
M       R       W       Y       P       W       L       R       P       D       F       E       K       L       V       A       S   L
.       .       .       .       T       T       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       T       T   .
65.7 -16.7 128.5        64.5 -19.9 130.3        66.9 -22.7 131.5        66.0 -25.8 129.7        67.1 -29.4 130.9        69.2 -30.4 127.8     71.4 -27.4 128.6        72.9 -29.3 131.5        75.3 -32.0 130.1        76.9 -29.2 128.1        76.9 -26.7 131.0        78.6 -29.4 133.1     81.8 -29.7 131.1        81.8 -26.0 130.4        82.2 -25.2 134.1        84.3 -28.3 134.6        87.0 -26.5 132.5    86.5 -23.1 134.2 87.2 -24.8 137.5        90.3 -26.9 136.4        91.9 -24.1 134.3        91.2 -25.8 130.9        88.8 -22.9 130.1    88.9 -21.4 126.6 89.0 -17.6 126.7        86.9 -17.5 123.5        83.8 -19.6 123.0        81.6 -19.9 119.9        78.4 -21.8 120.5    76.4 -23.0 117.5 72.8 -23.9 117.9        69.4 -23.9 116.3        66.9 -21.3 117.2        65.1 -21.8 120.5        67.7 -24.4 121.7    68.4 -22.5 124.8 71.4 -20.9 123.2        70.2 -17.9 125.1        70.3 -19.4 128.5        73.6 -21.3 128.3        75.7 -18.2 127.8    74.1 -16.3 130.7 74.1 -19.4 133.0        77.8 -19.8 132.3        78.8 -16.2 133.0        77.0 -16.2 136.4        79.4 -18.9 137.5    82.4 -16.9 136.6 81.1 -13.6 138.0        80.6 -14.9 141.5        82.7 -13.6 144.4        81.9 -16.6 146.7        80.7 -19.6 144.5    79.2 -22.6 146.2 80.7 -25.3 143.9        78.7 -25.6 140.7        76.6 -22.5 141.0        76.6 -19.1 142.8        75.6 -18.0 146.3    73.1 -15.2 145.4 74.5 -12.7 148.0        78.0 -11.6 146.9        78.5 -8.3 145.0 78.7 -10.2 141.8        75.6 -12.3 142.3        73.7 -9.2 143.5      74.8 -6.8 140.8 74.2 -9.8 138.5 70.6 -10.2 139.7        70.4 -6.4 139.2 71.7 -7.1 135.7 74.0 -4.0 135.8 77.6 -5.1 136.4      81.1 -3.7 135.7 82.4 -7.0 134.2 79.5 -8.2 132.2 79.4 -6.7 128.7 76.5 -7.3 126.2 77.5 -6.8 122.6 74.1 -6.4 121.0 74.1 -5.1 117.4      73.4 -1.3 116.8 69.7 -0.7 117.7 67.9 -0.2 114.4 70.3 -1.8 112.0 70.7 -5.6 111.3 74.4 -5.6 111.8 77.1 -4.7 114.4 79.7 -1.9 114.3      83.5 -1.7 114.3 82.9 1.0 117.0  81.1 -1.0 119.7 83.9 -3.6 119.5 86.8 -1.2 119.9 85.1 0.5 122.9  84.7 -2.8 124.7 88.3 -3.9 123.7      89.8 -0.9 125.5 87.2 -1.3 128.2 88.8 -4.6 129.1 92.3 -3.2 128.8 91.9 -1.8 132.3 91.6 -3.7 135.7 88.3 -5.5 136.6 86.3 -3.2 138.9      85.3 -6.1 141.2 88.7 -7.8 141.0 88.2 -11.1 139.2        87.1 -12.3 135.8        85.6 -10.1 132.9        83.1 -11.6 130.4    81.8 -10.7 126.9 78.9 -12.0 124.9        77.8 -11.6 121.3        74.2 -12.0 120.1        75.2 -13.4 116.7        78.7 -13.1 115.2    77.5 -13.8 111.7 75.7 -10.4 111.7        78.8 -8.2 112.1 80.6 -5.9 109.6 83.7 -7.5 107.9 85.8 -4.8 109.5 84.2 -5.5 112.9 85.6 -9.1 112.6      89.2 -8.1 112.3 88.8 -5.4 114.9 87.8 -8.1 117.3 90.6 -10.6 116.4        93.6 -8.6 117.7 92.2 -8.7 121.2 91.9 -12.5 121.2    95.5 -12.5 120.1 96.5 -10.2 123.0        94.2 -11.8 125.7        93.9 -9.5 128.8 94.7 -11.9 131.7        91.7 -13.9 133.1        89.1 -12.4 130.8     86.3 -14.5 129.1        84.5 -14.4 125.7        81.3 -15.9 124.4        80.5 -15.9 120.7        77.3 -17.4 119.5    76.0 -18.2 116.0 73.5 -20.3 114.2        75.8 -20.6 111.2        79.5 -20.8 112.0        80.6 -21.2 108.4        79.5 -17.8 107.3    82.1 -16.6 109.9 85.7 -15.6 109.1        87.9 -18.7 109.1        90.7 -16.8 110.8        88.2 -15.8 113.5        86.5 -19.2 114.1    90.0 -20.6 114.6 90.7 -18.5 117.7        87.6 -19.7 119.5        86.5 -23.1 120.6        83.4 -24.2 118.7        80.9 -26.1 120.8    77.9 -27.9 119.3 74.6 -27.5 121.1        73.0 -30.7 119.6        69.2 -30.8 118.8        68.0 -33.4 121.2        66.8 -36.7 119.7    63.3 -36.2 118.3 61.6 -38.6 120.7        62.8 -36.6 123.6        61.9 -33.2 122.0        58.4 -34.3 121.2        57.6 -35.6 124.7    59.0 -32.4 126.2 56.8 -30.5 123.8        53.6 -32.5 124.5        53.8 -30.9 127.9        54.2 -27.3 126.9        51.2 -27.5 124.5    48.6 -30.1 123.9 48.5 -30.9 120.2        48.7 -34.1 118.1        52.2 -35.6 118.2        52.1 -35.5 114.4        51.8 -31.8 114.5    54.3 -31.6 117.3 56.9 -33.4 115.1        56.1 -31.1 112.2        56.9 -28.0 114.3        60.2 -29.7 115.5        61.2 -30.5 111.9    60.2 -27.0 110.8 62.8 -25.7 113.3        65.7 -27.9 112.4        65.1 -29.8 115.6        65.1 -26.7 117.9        62.5 -27.5 120.5    62.4 -23.9 121.6 61.6 -22.5 118.2        59.2 -25.4 117.7        57.4 -24.4 120.9        57.2 -20.8 119.7        55.7 -22.0 116.5    52.5 -22.6 118.4 52.3 -19.7 120.9        51.0 -17.2 118.3        48.2 -18.8 116.5        50.9 -19.8 114.0        50.0 -23.4 113.8    46.4 -22.5 113.1 47.8 -20.1 110.4        49.7 -23.1 109.1        46.6 -25.3 109.0        45.0 -22.6 106.8        47.8 -23.0 104.4    47.6 -26.8 104.0 43.8 -26.5 103.4        44.3 -24.0 100.7        47.1 -26.1 99.2 44.9 -29.2 99.2 42.3 -27.4 97.2 44.7 -26.0 94.7 46.9 -29.1 94.1      44.1 -31.1 92.5 42.2 -28.1 91.1 45.1 -26.2 89.4 43.8 -22.9 90.9 47.0 -22.0 92.7 46.0 -18.4 92.8 43.6 -19.4 95.6 46.6 -19.4 98.0      46.7 -15.7 97.7 44.6 -15.2 100.8        46.6 -17.8 102.7        50.0 -16.3 101.8        49.4 -12.6 101.4        50.1 -11.5 104.9     53.0 -9.8 106.8 54.0 -13.4 107.8        54.5 -14.0 104.1        58.1 -15.2 104.4        57.5 -17.6 107.2        54.6 -18.9 105.2     56.4 -19.2 101.9        59.0 -21.3 103.7        56.2 -23.6 105.0        55.0 -24.0 101.4        58.6 -24.8 100.4    59.0 -27.6 102.9 56.0 -29.3 101.4        57.5 -28.8 97.9 60.7 -30.3 99.0 59.0 -33.4 100.5        57.0 -34.1 97.3 60.3 -33.9 95.5 62.0 -36.3 97.9      59.2 -38.8 97.5 59.9 -39.0 93.7 63.3 -40.3 94.6 61.9 -42.6 97.2 63.3 -40.7 100.2        62.2 -42.2 103.5        62.3 -39.0 105.6     59.6 -36.3 105.3        59.3 -33.1 107.2        55.6 -32.7 106.8        54.4 -35.9 108.5        51.5 -33.8 109.6    49.8 -34.3 106.2 51.3 -37.2 104.2        48.2 -37.2 102.1        49.2 -33.8 100.8        52.8 -34.5 99.9 51.5 -37.6 98.1 48.9 -36.0 95.9      51.3 -33.1 95.3 54.0 -35.5 94.1 51.3 -37.3 92.0 50.2 -34.2 90.0 53.6 -32.6 89.7 56.6 -34.0 87.9 59.9 -33.8 89.7 60.9 -31.0 87.3      57.8 -28.9 87.8 58.3 -29.2 91.5 62.0 -28.0 91.2 60.8 -25.0 89.2 58.2 -24.0 91.7 60.5 -24.7 94.7 62.8 -22.0 93.4 60.4 -19.2 92.5      58.9 -19.8 95.9 62.4 -19.6 97.2 63.7 -16.5 95.4 60.4 -14.7 95.9 60.3 -15.3 99.6 63.7 -13.7 99.7 62.8 -10.5 97.9 60.1 -10.1 100.5     62.5 -10.4 103.3        65.4 -8.5 101.8 64.0 -5.6 99.5  62.8 -2.7 101.7 59.2 -2.6 100.6 57.9 -4.3 97.4  54.2 -5.0 96.9  53.5 -8.2 98.9       50.4 -8.5 96.9  51.8 -8.1 93.4  54.8 -10.2 93.8 52.9 -13.1 95.2 50.1 -12.8 92.6 52.9 -13.0 90.1 54.5 -16.0 91.9 51.1 -17.7 91.9      50.0 -17.1 88.3 53.5 -18.0 87.3 53.3 -21.3 89.1 50.3 -22.1 87.0 52.1 -21.6 83.7 54.8 -24.0 84.7 52.0 -26.5 85.2 50.8 -26.1 81.6      52.0 -28.7 79.0 54.8 -27.5 76.7 56.2 -24.8 78.9 60.0 -24.6 79.4 60.6 -24.0 83.1 63.6 -22.0 84.5 67.2 -23.0 85.4 69.4 -21.4 88.1      71.8 -18.6 87.1 75.6 -17.8 87.3
```

and so on (the same structure)

Please note in  line 5; There is a space between x
and y and y and z, but each XYZ group is tab-separated from the next.

Now  I am unsure if the code down works and computing the distance between ( XYZ coordinates) correctly or not!

```
awk '
NR%6==5 { printf "%f\n", sqrt(($1-x)^2 + ($2-y)^2 + ($3-z)^2) }
       { x=$1; y=$2; z=$3 }' myfile.adataset
```

But I want the output to be like this, which is to print also the lines 1,2,3,4 , and the results:

```
4LGTD
247
M       S       E       K       L       Q       K       V       L       
.       .       E       E       H       H       H       H       H 
the result

1XXIJ
334
M       R       W       Y       P       W       L       R       P
        T       T       H       H       H       H       H
the result 

and so on
```

So after that, I want other code to delete blocks of lines(1,2,3,4,5)if the results of XYZ coordinates are bigger than (4.5)?
Any suggestions  code for first computing the distance and then deleting if the line 5 result is bigger than 4.5 by awk to do this?

Comment: Duplicate with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455964/how-to-delete-each-proteins-blocks-of-lines1-2-3-4-5if-the-results-of-xyz-coor
Same problems

Comment: `NR%5==5` condition is always false. `NR%5` is always between 0 and 4

Comment: All of rows in example contain only one column. So math expression with `$1`, `$2` and `$3` never works fine

Comment: Which rows you mean? In second rew i have so many letters each of them is column .when I print column 1 it gives me just one letter in the second row

Comment: with `awk` command, columns are (by default) separated by space or tabulation

Comment: It’s separated by space

Comment: Not in your question sample. You have only one number for each 5 lines block: 30.6 for the first, 60.0 for the second and 20.5 for the third.

Comment: Oh yea the output from my code above is just one column

Comment: The input (partially) is really important to reproduce your problem. The real code you have written is also important. Please edit your question and fix it

Comment: I want the results which is my output to be replaced in the line 5 of each  block of 5 lines.So i can sort each  protein block of lines if line 5 is less than 40.10 is it possible?!

Comment: We need to save in memory each block of 5 lines (NR%5 between 1 and 4), computing number on 5th line (NR%5 == 0), I think, and print the saved block if the result if less or equal to 40.1. Without input sample it's a little difficult for me to explain or propose a better solution

Comment: You mean not print the result just save it and print just if line 5 less or equal 40.1 ! But how can I modify the code to do it in this way?

Comment: The alternative approach is PFAM Stockholm format and parse this via Biopython, but I don't know how you import coordinates via this format (but can probably do it). It will do the secondary structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example you've provided, your awk command is returning an incorrect result ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), however one potential answer to your question is to print your desired outcome using two clauses:

`NR%6==0 (i.e. every 6 lines: 5 lines and 1 blank line) {do action}`

and

`NR%6!=0 (i.e. every other line) {do different action}`.

---

Example data:

```
cat test.txt

4LGTD
247
M       S       E       K       L       Q       K       V       L       A       R       A       G       H       G       S       R   T
.       .       E       E       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       T       T       S       S       .       H   .
-34.3 -28.9 16.3        -33.0 -26.8 13.4        -29.4 -25.4 13.3        -27.9 -22.6 11.2        -26.9 -24.1 7.8 -23.3 -22.9 8.2 -23.0 -24.7 11.5     -24.1 -27.9 9.9 -21.8 -27.7 6.9 -18.8 -26.7 9.0 -19.5 -29.7 11.3        -19.6 -31.9 8.2 -16.2 -30.7 7.2 -16.7 -28.2 4.4      -15.0 -25.1 5.8 -15.4 -22.7 8.7 -18.8 -21.3 9.7 -17.7 -17.9 8.3 -16.3 -19.3 5.1 -19.5 -21.2 4.5 -21.5 -18.0 5.1 -19.7 -16.2 2.3      -20.8 -19.1 -0.0        -24.4 -19.2 1.2 -24.6 -15.4 0.6 -23.5 -16.0 -3.0        -26.4 -18.4 -3.6        -24.1 -21.4 -4.0    -25.9 -23.6 -1.5 -29.3 -25.2 -2.0        -31.4 -27.0 0.5 -34.0 -29.5 -0.8        -33.9 -27.8 -4.2        -34.1 -24.2 -3.0        -31.3 -21.7 -2.9     -30.7 -21.0 0.8 -30.2 -17.5 2.2 -27.9 -16.3 4.9 -29.4 -17.1 8.3 -31.3 -20.1 7.0 -31.7 -23.1 9.4 -32.1 -26.8 8.7 -32.6 -30.1 10.5     -30.2 -32.9 9.7 -32.0 -36.0 8.4 -31.6 -38.7 5.7 -34.0 -36.6 3.6 -32.0 -33.4 3.7 -30.4 -32.7 0.4 -27.7 -30.0 0.6 -25.8 -29.0 -2.5     -23.0 -26.6 -3.0        -22.5 -25.6 -6.6        -25.0 -28.3 -7.5        -22.9 -31.1 -5.9        -24.6 -33.1 -3.2    -23.0 -33.1 0.2  -23.1 -36.0 2.6 -23.7 -34.9 6.2 -23.8 -36.9 9.4 -27.2 -37.3 11.1        -28.5 -37.1 14.7        -19.2 -38.7 17.8    -17.7 -36.6 20.6 -14.0 -37.3 20.3        -11.2 -35.4 22.0        -7.4 -35.3 21.2 -4.7 -34.3 23.6 -1.9 -32.6 21.6 1.6 -31.6 22.7  2.2 -28.4 20.7       5.8 -27.5 20.1  7.1 -23.9 19.9  7.1 -22.6 16.3  3.6 -24.0 15.4  0.7 -21.6 14.7  -2.8 -22.2 16.0 -4.8 -21.4 12.8 -6.4 -23.3 9.9       -4.8 -20.9 7.5  -1.6 -18.8 8.1  -1.1 -16.0 5.5  2.7 -16.4 6.0   3.0 -20.1 5.2   4.2 -21.3 8.7   3.5 -24.7 10.3  0.1 -24.9 11.9       -1.1 -27.3 14.7 -3.6 -28.9 12.3 -1.0 -30.0 9.8  -0.7 -33.4 11.5 -4.0 -34.7 12.9 -6.1 -37.9 12.3 -8.5 -37.7 9.3  -12.2 -38.1 10.1     -15.3 -39.0 8.2 -17.5 -36.0 7.6 -16.2 -34.0 10.6        -13.2 -31.8 11.6        -10.9 -31.0 14.5        -11.7 -27.8 16.4     -8.8 -26.3 18.5 -9.8 -25.6 22.1 -8.4 -22.1 22.1 -5.0 -20.9 20.9 -1.5 -21.1 22.2 1.2 -18.6 21.2  3.8 -19.7 18.6  6.6 -20.0 21.1       4.5 -21.3 23.9  4.7 -25.1 24.5  2.3 -27.7 25.8  -1.3 -29.0 25.9 -3.8 -28.1 23.2 -7.0 -30.0 23.1 -8.9 -30.7 19.9 -12.5 -32.0 19.6     -14.9 -32.8 16.9        -17.6 -31.5 19.2        -17.9 -27.7 18.8        -20.2 -27.3 21.8        -17.6 -29.0 24.0        -15.0 -26.8 22.4     -16.8 -23.5 23.1        -17.7 -24.6 26.6        -14.1 -25.3 27.4        -12.9 -21.9 26.0        -15.6 -19.6 27.2    -14.8 -18.2 30.6 -18.4 -18.5 31.9        -17.5 -22.1 32.5        -14.3 -21.2 34.4        -12.2 -24.1 33.1        -8.7 -24.1 34.5 -5.7 -23.6 32.3      -2.5 -24.5 34.2 0.9 -23.2 33.2  4.4 -23.9 34.3  6.1 -20.6 34.0  9.8 -20.0 34.3  10.1 -16.4 35.4 13.0 -14.0 35.5 13.3 -11.2 38.1      12.7 -10.5 41.8 9.7 -12.2 43.3  8.4 -12.0 46.8  5.2 -13.0 48.6  3.7 -9.5 48.4   3.8 -9.8 44.6   2.2 -13.2 44.8  -0.6 -11.7 47.0      -1.0 -8.9 44.5  -1.3 -11.3 41.5 -3.9 -13.4 43.4 -6.1 -10.5 44.4 -6.1 -8.6 41.1  -3.9 -6.2 39.3  -4.5 -3.7 36.4  -3.6 -4.8 32.9       -3.8 -2.6 29.8  -7.0 -4.4 29.0  -8.5 -4.4 32.5  -8.2 -6.2 35.8  -6.8 -9.7 35.9  -5.7 -12.2 38.6 -4.2 -15.6 38.7 -6.6 -18.1 40.2      -3.8 -20.0 41.8 -0.0 -19.4 42.0 2.4 -21.9 43.4  6.2 -21.7 43.7  7.6 -24.7 41.8  11.4 -24.5 42.2 14.2 -22.0 42.2 17.4 -20.5 41.0      18.6 -17.0 41.7 16.7 -14.6 39.4 15.1 -17.6 37.8 12.2 -19.4 39.4 9.4 -21.8 38.3  5.8 -21.1 39.2  2.7 -23.1 38.4  -0.3 -20.8 37.8      -3.8 -21.1 36.7 -6.3 -18.9 34.9 -9.9 -19.4 34.1 -9.9 -17.1 31.1 -7.6 -16.7 28.1 -6.8 -13.1 27.2 -4.0 -12.5 24.7 -0.6 -13.1 26.3      -2.2 -12.9 29.7 0.3 -14.9 31.8  3.2 -12.8 30.5  1.3 -9.5 31.1   0.4 -10.5 34.6  4.0 -11.2 35.6  5.1 -8.0 33.8   2.5 -6.0 35.8        4.6 -6.8 38.9   8.0 -6.3 37.2   8.8 -9.9 36.2   9.7 -11.4 32.9  8.9 -14.8 31.5  11.6 -17.1 30.0 9.5 -20.2 29.5  5.8 -21.0 29.3       4.3 -24.5 29.1  0.6 -25.3 29.3  0.5 -28.5 31.4  -3.2 -28.9 32.0 -6.5 -27.9 30.5 -9.5 -28.7 32.7 -9.1 -32.2 34.0 -6.7 -33.3 31.2      -3.0 -32.9 32.1 -0.4 -33.0 29.4 -0.1 -36.8 28.8 2.9 -38.3 30.7  4.2 -40.6 28.0  3.5 -38.2 25.2  6.4 -36.4 23.5  6.5 -32.9 22.0       4.6 -32.8 18.6  2.5 -35.9 19.2  -1.1 -36.5 20.3 -3.4 -39.1 21.9 -7.1 -39.7 22.0 -9.2 -39.8 25.2 -11.5 -42.8 25.8    -15.2 -42.7 26.7 -14.8 -42.3 30.4        -12.3 -39.5 30.0        -14.2 -37.7 27.3        -17.3 -38.0 29.6        -15.4 -36.5 32.6    -14.3 -33.6 30.4 -17.9 -33.1 29.4        -19.2 -33.2 33.0        -16.7 -30.4 33.8        -18.7 -28.1 31.6        -22.2 -29.4 32.6    -22.6 -31.6 29.5 -24.2 -35.0 30.3        -22.3 -38.2 29.6        -22.5 -39.9 26.3        -22.8 -43.7 25.4

1XXIJ
334
M       R       W       Y       P       W       L       R       P       D       F       E       K       L       V       A       S   L
.       .       .       .       T       T       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       T       T   .
65.7 -16.7 128.5        64.5 -19.9 130.3        66.9 -22.7 131.5        66.0 -25.8 129.7        67.1 -29.4 130.9        69.2 -30.4 127.8     71.4 -27.4 128.6        72.9 -29.3 131.5        75.3 -32.0 130.1        76.9 -29.2 128.1        76.9 -26.7 131.0        78.6 -29.4 133.1     81.8 -29.7 131.1        81.8 -26.0 130.4        82.2 -25.2 134.1        84.3 -28.3 134.6        87.0 -26.5 132.5    86.5 -23.1 134.2 87.2 -24.8 137.5        90.3 -26.9 136.4        91.9 -24.1 134.3        91.2 -25.8 130.9        88.8 -22.9 130.1    88.9 -21.4 126.6 89.0 -17.6 126.7        86.9 -17.5 123.5        83.8 -19.6 123.0        81.6 -19.9 119.9        78.4 -21.8 120.5    76.4 -23.0 117.5 72.8 -23.9 117.9        69.4 -23.9 116.3        66.9 -21.3 117.2        65.1 -21.8 120.5        67.7 -24.4 121.7    68.4 -22.5 124.8 71.4 -20.9 123.2        70.2 -17.9 125.1        70.3 -19.4 128.5        73.6 -21.3 128.3        75.7 -18.2 127.8    74.1 -16.3 130.7 74.1 -19.4 133.0        77.8 -19.8 132.3        78.8 -16.2 133.0        77.0 -16.2 136.4        79.4 -18.9 137.5    82.4 -16.9 136.6 81.1 -13.6 138.0        80.6 -14.9 141.5        82.7 -13.6 144.4        81.9 -16.6 146.7        80.7 -19.6 144.5    79.2 -22.6 146.2 80.7 -25.3 143.9        78.7 -25.6 140.7        76.6 -22.5 141.0        76.6 -19.1 142.8        75.6 -18.0 146.3    73.1 -15.2 145.4 74.5 -12.7 148.0        78.0 -11.6 146.9        78.5 -8.3 145.0 78.7 -10.2 141.8        75.6 -12.3 142.3        73.7 -9.2 143.5      74.8 -6.8 140.8 74.2 -9.8 138.5 70.6 -10.2 139.7        70.4 -6.4 139.2 71.7 -7.1 135.7 74.0 -4.0 135.8 77.6 -5.1 136.4      81.1 -3.7 135.7 82.4 -7.0 134.2 79.5 -8.2 132.2 79.4 -6.7 128.7 76.5 -7.3 126.2 77.5 -6.8 122.6 74.1 -6.4 121.0 74.1 -5.1 117.4      73.4 -1.3 116.8 69.7 -0.7 117.7 67.9 -0.2 114.4 70.3 -1.8 112.0 70.7 -5.6 111.3 74.4 -5.6 111.8 77.1 -4.7 114.4 79.7 -1.9 114.3      83.5 -1.7 114.3 82.9 1.0 117.0  81.1 -1.0 119.7 83.9 -3.6 119.5 86.8 -1.2 119.9 85.1 0.5 122.9  84.7 -2.8 124.7 88.3 -3.9 123.7      89.8 -0.9 125.5 87.2 -1.3 128.2 88.8 -4.6 129.1 92.3 -3.2 128.8 91.9 -1.8 132.3 91.6 -3.7 135.7 88.3 -5.5 136.6 86.3 -3.2 138.9      85.3 -6.1 141.2 88.7 -7.8 141.0 88.2 -11.1 139.2        87.1 -12.3 135.8        85.6 -10.1 132.9        83.1 -11.6 130.4    81.8 -10.7 126.9 78.9 -12.0 124.9        77.8 -11.6 121.3        74.2 -12.0 120.1        75.2 -13.4 116.7        78.7 -13.1 115.2    77.5 -13.8 111.7 75.7 -10.4 111.7        78.8 -8.2 112.1 80.6 -5.9 109.6 83.7 -7.5 107.9 85.8 -4.8 109.5 84.2 -5.5 112.9 85.6 -9.1 112.6      89.2 -8.1 112.3 88.8 -5.4 114.9 87.8 -8.1 117.3 90.6 -10.6 116.4        93.6 -8.6 117.7 92.2 -8.7 121.2 91.9 -12.5 121.2    95.5 -12.5 120.1 96.5 -10.2 123.0        94.2 -11.8 125.7        93.9 -9.5 128.8 94.7 -11.9 131.7        91.7 -13.9 133.1        89.1 -12.4 130.8     86.3 -14.5 129.1        84.5 -14.4 125.7        81.3 -15.9 124.4        80.5 -15.9 120.7        77.3 -17.4 119.5    76.0 -18.2 116.0 73.5 -20.3 114.2        75.8 -20.6 111.2        79.5 -20.8 112.0        80.6 -21.2 108.4        79.5 -17.8 107.3    82.1 -16.6 109.9 85.7 -15.6 109.1        87.9 -18.7 109.1        90.7 -16.8 110.8        88.2 -15.8 113.5        86.5 -19.2 114.1    90.0 -20.6 114.6 90.7 -18.5 117.7        87.6 -19.7 119.5        86.5 -23.1 120.6        83.4 -24.2 118.7        80.9 -26.1 120.8    77.9 -27.9 119.3 74.6 -27.5 121.1        73.0 -30.7 119.6        69.2 -30.8 118.8        68.0 -33.4 121.2        66.8 -36.7 119.7    63.3 -36.2 118.3 61.6 -38.6 120.7        62.8 -36.6 123.6        61.9 -33.2 122.0        58.4 -34.3 121.2        57.6 -35.6 124.7    59.0 -32.4 126.2 56.8 -30.5 123.8        53.6 -32.5 124.5        53.8 -30.9 127.9        54.2 -27.3 126.9        51.2 -27.5 124.5    48.6 -30.1 123.9 48.5 -30.9 120.2        48.7 -34.1 118.1        52.2 -35.6 118.2        52.1 -35.5 114.4        51.8 -31.8 114.5    54.3 -31.6 117.3 56.9 -33.4 115.1        56.1 -31.1 112.2        56.9 -28.0 114.3        60.2 -29.7 115.5        61.2 -30.5 111.9    60.2 -27.0 110.8 62.8 -25.7 113.3        65.7 -27.9 112.4        65.1 -29.8 115.6        65.1 -26.7 117.9        62.5 -27.5 120.5    62.4 -23.9 121.6 61.6 -22.5 118.2        59.2 -25.4 117.7        57.4 -24.4 120.9        57.2 -20.8 119.7        55.7 -22.0 116.5    52.5 -22.6 118.4 52.3 -19.7 120.9        51.0 -17.2 118.3        48.2 -18.8 116.5        50.9 -19.8 114.0        50.0 -23.4 113.8    46.4 -22.5 113.1 47.8 -20.1 110.4        49.7 -23.1 109.1        46.6 -25.3 109.0        45.0 -22.6 106.8        47.8 -23.0 104.4    47.6 -26.8 104.0 43.8 -26.5 103.4        44.3 -24.0 100.7        47.1 -26.1 99.2 44.9 -29.2 99.2 42.3 -27.4 97.2 44.7 -26.0 94.7 46.9 -29.1 94.1      44.1 -31.1 92.5 42.2 -28.1 91.1 45.1 -26.2 89.4 43.8 -22.9 90.9 47.0 -22.0 92.7 46.0 -18.4 92.8 43.6 -19.4 95.6 46.6 -19.4 98.0      46.7 -15.7 97.7 44.6 -15.2 100.8        46.6 -17.8 102.7        50.0 -16.3 101.8        49.4 -12.6 101.4        50.1 -11.5 104.9     53.0 -9.8 106.8 54.0 -13.4 107.8        54.5 -14.0 104.1        58.1 -15.2 104.4        57.5 -17.6 107.2        54.6 -18.9 105.2     56.4 -19.2 101.9        59.0 -21.3 103.7        56.2 -23.6 105.0        55.0 -24.0 101.4        58.6 -24.8 100.4    59.0 -27.6 102.9 56.0 -29.3 101.4        57.5 -28.8 97.9 60.7 -30.3 99.0 59.0 -33.4 100.5        57.0 -34.1 97.3 60.3 -33.9 95.5 62.0 -36.3 97.9      59.2 -38.8 97.5 59.9 -39.0 93.7 63.3 -40.3 94.6 61.9 -42.6 97.2 63.3 -40.7 100.2        62.2 -42.2 103.5        62.3 -39.0 105.6     59.6 -36.3 105.3        59.3 -33.1 107.2        55.6 -32.7 106.8        54.4 -35.9 108.5        51.5 -33.8 109.6    49.8 -34.3 106.2 51.3 -37.2 104.2        48.2 -37.2 102.1        49.2 -33.8 100.8        52.8 -34.5 99.9 51.5 -37.6 98.1 48.9 -36.0 95.9      51.3 -33.1 95.3 54.0 -35.5 94.1 51.3 -37.3 92.0 50.2 -34.2 90.0 53.6 -32.6 89.7 56.6 -34.0 87.9 59.9 -33.8 89.7 60.9 -31.0 87.3      57.8 -28.9 87.8 58.3 -29.2 91.5 62.0 -28.0 91.2 60.8 -25.0 89.2 58.2 -24.0 91.7 60.5 -24.7 94.7 62.8 -22.0 93.4 60.4 -19.2 92.5      58.9 -19.8 95.9 62.4 -19.6 97.2 63.7 -16.5 95.4 60.4 -14.7 95.9 60.3 -15.3 99.6 63.7 -13.7 99.7 62.8 -10.5 97.9 60.1 -10.1 100.5     62.5 -10.4 103.3        65.4 -8.5 101.8 64.0 -5.6 99.5  62.8 -2.7 101.7 59.2 -2.6 100.6 57.9 -4.3 97.4  54.2 -5.0 96.9  53.5 -8.2 98.9       50.4 -8.5 96.9  51.8 -8.1 93.4  54.8 -10.2 93.8 52.9 -13.1 95.2 50.1 -12.8 92.6 52.9 -13.0 90.1 54.5 -16.0 91.9 51.1 -17.7 91.9      50.0 -17.1 88.3 53.5 -18.0 87.3 53.3 -21.3 89.1 50.3 -22.1 87.0 52.1 -21.6 83.7 54.8 -24.0 84.7 52.0 -26.5 85.2 50.8 -26.1 81.6      52.0 -28.7 79.0 54.8 -27.5 76.7 56.2 -24.8 78.9 60.0 -24.6 79.4 60.6 -24.0 83.1 63.6 -22.0 84.5 67.2 -23.0 85.4 69.4 -21.4 88.1      71.8 -18.6 87.1 75.6 -17.8 87.3
```

Example command:

```
awk 'NR%6 != 0 {print} NR%6==0 {res=(sqrt(($1-x)^2 + ($2-y)^2 + ($3-z)^2)); if(res <= 4.5){printf "%f\n", res} else{print}} {x=$1; y=$2; z=$3}'

4LGTD
247
M       S       E       K       L       Q       K       V       L       A       R       A       G       H       G       S       R   T
.       .       E       E       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       T       T       S       S       .       H   .
-34.3 -28.9 16.3        -33.0 -26.8 13.4        -29.4 -25.4 13.3        -27.9 -22.6 11.2        -26.9 -24.1 7.8 -23.3 -22.9 8.2 -23.0 -24.7 11.5     -24.1 -27.9 9.9 -21.8 -27.7 6.9 -18.8 -26.7 9.0 -19.5 -29.7 11.3        -19.6 -31.9 8.2 -16.2 -30.7 7.2 -16.7 -28.2 4.4      -15.0 -25.1 5.8 -15.4 -22.7 8.7 -18.8 -21.3 9.7 -17.7 -17.9 8.3 -16.3 -19.3 5.1 -19.5 -21.2 4.5 -21.5 -18.0 5.1 -19.7 -16.2 2.3      -20.8 -19.1 -0.0        -24.4 -19.2 1.2 -24.6 -15.4 0.6 -23.5 -16.0 -3.0        -26.4 -18.4 -3.6        -24.1 -21.4 -4.0    -25.9 -23.6 -1.5 -29.3 -25.2 -2.0        -31.4 -27.0 0.5 -34.0 -29.5 -0.8        -33.9 -27.8 -4.2        -34.1 -24.2 -3.0        -31.3 -21.7 -2.9     -30.7 -21.0 0.8 -30.2 -17.5 2.2 -27.9 -16.3 4.9 -29.4 -17.1 8.3 -31.3 -20.1 7.0 -31.7 -23.1 9.4 -32.1 -26.8 8.7 -32.6 -30.1 10.5     -30.2 -32.9 9.7 -32.0 -36.0 8.4 -31.6 -38.7 5.7 -34.0 -36.6 3.6 -32.0 -33.4 3.7 -30.4 -32.7 0.4 -27.7 -30.0 0.6 -25.8 -29.0 -2.5     -23.0 -26.6 -3.0        -22.5 -25.6 -6.6        -25.0 -28.3 -7.5        -22.9 -31.1 -5.9        -24.6 -33.1 -3.2    -23.0 -33.1 0.2  -23.1 -36.0 2.6 -23.7 -34.9 6.2 -23.8 -36.9 9.4 -27.2 -37.3 11.1        -28.5 -37.1 14.7        -19.2 -38.7 17.8    -17.7 -36.6 20.6 -14.0 -37.3 20.3        -11.2 -35.4 22.0        -7.4 -35.3 21.2 -4.7 -34.3 23.6 -1.9 -32.6 21.6 1.6 -31.6 22.7  2.2 -28.4 20.7       5.8 -27.5 20.1  7.1 -23.9 19.9  7.1 -22.6 16.3  3.6 -24.0 15.4  0.7 -21.6 14.7  -2.8 -22.2 16.0 -4.8 -21.4 12.8 -6.4 -23.3 9.9       -4.8 -20.9 7.5  -1.6 -18.8 8.1  -1.1 -16.0 5.5  2.7 -16.4 6.0   3.0 -20.1 5.2   4.2 -21.3 8.7   3.5 -24.7 10.3  0.1 -24.9 11.9       -1.1 -27.3 14.7 -3.6 -28.9 12.3 -1.0 -30.0 9.8  -0.7 -33.4 11.5 -4.0 -34.7 12.9 -6.1 -37.9 12.3 -8.5 -37.7 9.3  -12.2 -38.1 10.1     -15.3 -39.0 8.2 -17.5 -36.0 7.6 -16.2 -34.0 10.6        -13.2 -31.8 11.6        -10.9 -31.0 14.5        -11.7 -27.8 16.4     -8.8 -26.3 18.5 -9.8 -25.6 22.1 -8.4 -22.1 22.1 -5.0 -20.9 20.9 -1.5 -21.1 22.2 1.2 -18.6 21.2  3.8 -19.7 18.6  6.6 -20.0 21.1       4.5 -21.3 23.9  4.7 -25.1 24.5  2.3 -27.7 25.8  -1.3 -29.0 25.9 -3.8 -28.1 23.2 -7.0 -30.0 23.1 -8.9 -30.7 19.9 -12.5 -32.0 19.6     -14.9 -32.8 16.9        -17.6 -31.5 19.2        -17.9 -27.7 18.8        -20.2 -27.3 21.8        -17.6 -29.0 24.0        -15.0 -26.8 22.4     -16.8 -23.5 23.1        -17.7 -24.6 26.6        -14.1 -25.3 27.4        -12.9 -21.9 26.0        -15.6 -19.6 27.2    -14.8 -18.2 30.6 -18.4 -18.5 31.9        -17.5 -22.1 32.5        -14.3 -21.2 34.4        -12.2 -24.1 33.1        -8.7 -24.1 34.5 -5.7 -23.6 32.3      -2.5 -24.5 34.2 0.9 -23.2 33.2  4.4 -23.9 34.3  6.1 -20.6 34.0  9.8 -20.0 34.3  10.1 -16.4 35.4 13.0 -14.0 35.5 13.3 -11.2 38.1      12.7 -10.5 41.8 9.7 -12.2 43.3  8.4 -12.0 46.8  5.2 -13.0 48.6  3.7 -9.5 48.4   3.8 -9.8 44.6   2.2 -13.2 44.8  -0.6 -11.7 47.0      -1.0 -8.9 44.5  -1.3 -11.3 41.5 -3.9 -13.4 43.4 -6.1 -10.5 44.4 -6.1 -8.6 41.1  -3.9 -6.2 39.3  -4.5 -3.7 36.4  -3.6 -4.8 32.9       -3.8 -2.6 29.8  -7.0 -4.4 29.0  -8.5 -4.4 32.5  -8.2 -6.2 35.8  -6.8 -9.7 35.9  -5.7 -12.2 38.6 -4.2 -15.6 38.7 -6.6 -18.1 40.2      -3.8 -20.0 41.8 -0.0 -19.4 42.0 2.4 -21.9 43.4  6.2 -21.7 43.7  7.6 -24.7 41.8  11.4 -24.5 42.2 14.2 -22.0 42.2 17.4 -20.5 41.0      18.6 -17.0 41.7 16.7 -14.6 39.4 15.1 -17.6 37.8 12.2 -19.4 39.4 9.4 -21.8 38.3  5.8 -21.1 39.2  2.7 -23.1 38.4  -0.3 -20.8 37.8      -3.8 -21.1 36.7 -6.3 -18.9 34.9 -9.9 -19.4 34.1 -9.9 -17.1 31.1 -7.6 -16.7 28.1 -6.8 -13.1 27.2 -4.0 -12.5 24.7 -0.6 -13.1 26.3      -2.2 -12.9 29.7 0.3 -14.9 31.8  3.2 -12.8 30.5  1.3 -9.5 31.1   0.4 -10.5 34.6  4.0 -11.2 35.6  5.1 -8.0 33.8   2.5 -6.0 35.8        4.6 -6.8 38.9   8.0 -6.3 37.2   8.8 -9.9 36.2   9.7 -11.4 32.9  8.9 -14.8 31.5  11.6 -17.1 30.0 9.5 -20.2 29.5  5.8 -21.0 29.3       4.3 -24.5 29.1  0.6 -25.3 29.3  0.5 -28.5 31.4  -3.2 -28.9 32.0 -6.5 -27.9 30.5 -9.5 -28.7 32.7 -9.1 -32.2 34.0 -6.7 -33.3 31.2      -3.0 -32.9 32.1 -0.4 -33.0 29.4 -0.1 -36.8 28.8 2.9 -38.3 30.7  4.2 -40.6 28.0  3.5 -38.2 25.2  6.4 -36.4 23.5  6.5 -32.9 22.0       4.6 -32.8 18.6  2.5 -35.9 19.2  -1.1 -36.5 20.3 -3.4 -39.1 21.9 -7.1 -39.7 22.0 -9.2 -39.8 25.2 -11.5 -42.8 25.8    -15.2 -42.7 26.7 -14.8 -42.3 30.4        -12.3 -39.5 30.0        -14.2 -37.7 27.3        -17.3 -38.0 29.6        -15.4 -36.5 32.6    -14.3 -33.6 30.4 -17.9 -33.1 29.4        -19.2 -33.2 33.0        -16.7 -30.4 33.8        -18.7 -28.1 31.6        -22.2 -29.4 32.6    -22.6 -31.6 29.5 -24.2 -35.0 30.3        -22.3 -38.2 29.6        -22.5 -39.9 26.3        -22.8 -43.7 25.4

1XXIJ
334
M       R       W       Y       P       W       L       R       P       D       F       E       K       L       V       A       S   L
.       .       .       .       T       T       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       H       T       T   .
65.7 -16.7 128.5        64.5 -19.9 130.3        66.9 -22.7 131.5        66.0 -25.8 129.7        67.1 -29.4 130.9        69.2 -30.4 127.8     71.4 -27.4 128.6        72.9 -29.3 131.5        75.3 -32.0 130.1        76.9 -29.2 128.1        76.9 -26.7 131.0        78.6 -29.4 133.1     81.8 -29.7 131.1        81.8 -26.0 130.4        82.2 -25.2 134.1        84.3 -28.3 134.6        87.0 -26.5 132.5    86.5 -23.1 134.2 87.2 -24.8 137.5        90.3 -26.9 136.4        91.9 -24.1 134.3        91.2 -25.8 130.9        88.8 -22.9 130.1    88.9 -21.4 126.6 89.0 -17.6 126.7        86.9 -17.5 123.5        83.8 -19.6 123.0        81.6 -19.9 119.9        78.4 -21.8 120.5    76.4 -23.0 117.5 72.8 -23.9 117.9        69.4 -23.9 116.3        66.9 -21.3 117.2        65.1 -21.8 120.5        67.7 -24.4 121.7    68.4 -22.5 124.8 71.4 -20.9 123.2        70.2 -17.9 125.1        70.3 -19.4 128.5        73.6 -21.3 128.3        75.7 -18.2 127.8    74.1 -16.3 130.7 74.1 -19.4 133.0        77.8 -19.8 132.3        78.8 -16.2 133.0        77.0 -16.2 136.4        79.4 -18.9 137.5    82.4 -16.9 136.6 81.1 -13.6 138.0        80.6 -14.9 141.5        82.7 -13.6 144.4        81.9 -16.6 146.7        80.7 -19.6 144.5    79.2 -22.6 146.2 80.7 -25.3 143.9        78.7 -25.6 140.7        76.6 -22.5 141.0        76.6 -19.1 142.8        75.6 -18.0 146.3    73.1 -15.2 145.4 74.5 -12.7 148.0        78.0 -11.6 146.9        78.5 -8.3 145.0 78.7 -10.2 141.8        75.6 -12.3 142.3        73.7 -9.2 143.5      74.8 -6.8 140.8 74.2 -9.8 138.5 70.6 -10.2 139.7        70.4 -6.4 139.2 71.7 -7.1 135.7 74.0 -4.0 135.8 77.6 -5.1 136.4      81.1 -3.7 135.7 82.4 -7.0 134.2 79.5 -8.2 132.2 79.4 -6.7 128.7 76.5 -7.3 126.2 77.5 -6.8 122.6 74.1 -6.4 121.0 74.1 -5.1 117.4      73.4 -1.3 116.8 69.7 -0.7 117.7 67.9 -0.2 114.4 70.3 -1.8 112.0 70.7 -5.6 111.3 74.4 -5.6 111.8 77.1 -4.7 114.4 79.7 -1.9 114.3      83.5 -1.7 114.3 82.9 1.0 117.0  81.1 -1.0 119.7 83.9 -3.6 119.5 86.8 -1.2 119.9 85.1 0.5 122.9  84.7 -2.8 124.7 88.3 -3.9 123.7      89.8 -0.9 125.5 87.2 -1.3 128.2 88.8 -4.6 129.1 92.3 -3.2 128.8 91.9 -1.8 132.3 91.6 -3.7 135.7 88.3 -5.5 136.6 86.3 -3.2 138.9      85.3 -6.1 141.2 88.7 -7.8 141.0 88.2 -11.1 139.2        87.1 -12.3 135.8        85.6 -10.1 132.9        83.1 -11.6 130.4    81.8 -10.7 126.9 78.9 -12.0 124.9        77.8 -11.6 121.3        74.2 -12.0 120.1        75.2 -13.4 116.7        78.7 -13.1 115.2    77.5 -13.8 111.7 75.7 -10.4 111.7        78.8 -8.2 112.1 80.6 -5.9 109.6 83.7 -7.5 107.9 85.8 -4.8 109.5 84.2 -5.5 112.9 85.6 -9.1 112.6      89.2 -8.1 112.3 88.8 -5.4 114.9 87.8 -8.1 117.3 90.6 -10.6 116.4        93.6 -8.6 117.7 92.2 -8.7 121.2 91.9 -12.5 121.2    95.5 -12.5 120.1 96.5 -10.2 123.0        94.2 -11.8 125.7        93.9 -9.5 128.8 94.7 -11.9 131.7        91.7 -13.9 133.1        89.1 -12.4 130.8     86.3 -14.5 129.1        84.5 -14.4 125.7        81.3 -15.9 124.4        80.5 -15.9 120.7        77.3 -17.4 119.5    76.0 -18.2 116.0 73.5 -20.3 114.2        75.8 -20.6 111.2        79.5 -20.8 112.0        80.6 -21.2 108.4        79.5 -17.8 107.3    82.1 -16.6 109.9 85.7 -15.6 109.1        87.9 -18.7 109.1        90.7 -16.8 110.8        88.2 -15.8 113.5        86.5 -19.2 114.1    90.0 -20.6 114.6 90.7 -18.5 117.7        87.6 -19.7 119.5        86.5 -23.1 120.6        83.4 -24.2 118.7        80.9 -26.1 120.8    77.9 -27.9 119.3 74.6 -27.5 121.1        73.0 -30.7 119.6        69.2 -30.8 118.8        68.0 -33.4 121.2        66.8 -36.7 119.7    63.3 -36.2 118.3 61.6 -38.6 120.7        62.8 -36.6 123.6        61.9 -33.2 122.0        58.4 -34.3 121.2        57.6 -35.6 124.7    59.0 -32.4 126.2 56.8 -30.5 123.8        53.6 -32.5 124.5        53.8 -30.9 127.9        54.2 -27.3 126.9        51.2 -27.5 124.5    48.6 -30.1 123.9 48.5 -30.9 120.2        48.7 -34.1 118.1        52.2 -35.6 118.2        52.1 -35.5 114.4        51.8 -31.8 114.5    54.3 -31.6 117.3 56.9 -33.4 115.1        56.1 -31.1 112.2        56.9 -28.0 114.3        60.2 -29.7 115.5        61.2 -30.5 111.9    60.2 -27.0 110.8 62.8 -25.7 113.3        65.7 -27.9 112.4        65.1 -29.8 115.6        65.1 -26.7 117.9        62.5 -27.5 120.5    62.4 -23.9 121.6 61.6 -22.5 118.2        59.2 -25.4 117.7        57.4 -24.4 120.9        57.2 -20.8 119.7        55.7 -22.0 116.5    52.5 -22.6 118.4 52.3 -19.7 120.9        51.0 -17.2 118.3        48.2 -18.8 116.5        50.9 -19.8 114.0        50.0 -23.4 113.8    46.4 -22.5 113.1 47.8 -20.1 110.4        49.7 -23.1 109.1        46.6 -25.3 109.0        45.0 -22.6 106.8        47.8 -23.0 104.4    47.6 -26.8 104.0 43.8 -26.5 103.4        44.3 -24.0 100.7        47.1 -26.1 99.2 44.9 -29.2 99.2 42.3 -27.4 97.2 44.7 -26.0 94.7 46.9 -29.1 94.1      44.1 -31.1 92.5 42.2 -28.1 91.1 45.1 -26.2 89.4 43.8 -22.9 90.9 47.0 -22.0 92.7 46.0 -18.4 92.8 43.6 -19.4 95.6 46.6 -19.4 98.0      46.7 -15.7 97.7 44.6 -15.2 100.8        46.6 -17.8 102.7        50.0 -16.3 101.8        49.4 -12.6 101.4        50.1 -11.5 104.9     53.0 -9.8 106.8 54.0 -13.4 107.8        54.5 -14.0 104.1        58.1 -15.2 104.4        57.5 -17.6 107.2        54.6 -18.9 105.2     56.4 -19.2 101.9        59.0 -21.3 103.7        56.2 -23.6 105.0        55.0 -24.0 101.4        58.6 -24.8 100.4    59.0 -27.6 102.9 56.0 -29.3 101.4        57.5 -28.8 97.9 60.7 -30.3 99.0 59.0 -33.4 100.5        57.0 -34.1 97.3 60.3 -33.9 95.5 62.0 -36.3 97.9      59.2 -38.8 97.5 59.9 -39.0 93.7 63.3 -40.3 94.6 61.9 -42.6 97.2 63.3 -40.7 100.2        62.2 -42.2 103.5        62.3 -39.0 105.6     59.6 -36.3 105.3        59.3 -33.1 107.2        55.6 -32.7 106.8        54.4 -35.9 108.5        51.5 -33.8 109.6    49.8 -34.3 106.2 51.3 -37.2 104.2        48.2 -37.2 102.1        49.2 -33.8 100.8        52.8 -34.5 99.9 51.5 -37.6 98.1 48.9 -36.0 95.9      51.3 -33.1 95.3 54.0 -35.5 94.1 51.3 -37.3 92.0 50.2 -34.2 90.0 53.6 -32.6 89.7 56.6 -34.0 87.9 59.9 -33.8 89.7 60.9 -31.0 87.3      57.8 -28.9 87.8 58.3 -29.2 91.5 62.0 -28.0 91.2 60.8 -25.0 89.2 58.2 -24.0 91.7 60.5 -24.7 94.7 62.8 -22.0 93.4 60.4 -19.2 92.5      58.9 -19.8 95.9 62.4 -19.6 97.2 63.7 -16.5 95.4 60.4 -14.7 95.9 60.3 -15.3 99.6 63.7 -13.7 99.7 62.8 -10.5 97.9 60.1 -10.1 100.5     62.5 -10.4 103.3        65.4 -8.5 101.8 64.0 -5.6 99.5  62.8 -2.7 101.7 59.2 -2.6 100.6 57.9 -4.3 97.4  54.2 -5.0 96.9  53.5 -8.2 98.9       50.4 -8.5 96.9  51.8 -8.1 93.4  54.8 -10.2 93.8 52.9 -13.1 95.2 50.1 -12.8 92.6 52.9 -13.0 90.1 54.5 -16.0 91.9 51.1 -17.7 91.9      50.0 -17.1 88.3 53.5 -18.0 87.3 53.3 -21.3 89.1 50.3 -22.1 87.0 52.1 -21.6 83.7 54.8 -24.0 84.7 52.0 -26.5 85.2 50.8 -26.1 81.6      52.0 -28.7 79.0 54.8 -27.5 76.7 56.2 -24.8 78.9 60.0 -24.6 79.4 60.6 -24.0 83.1 63.6 -22.0 84.5 67.2 -23.0 85.4 69.4 -21.4 88.1      71.8 -18.6 87.1 75.6 -17.8 87.3
```

NB. in both of these 'blocks' the equation is >4.5, so the entire line is printed. Is this your desired outcome?

Comment: What about if I want awk  code just to print the lines (1,2,3,4,5)if line 5 is less or equal 4.5?!

Comment: I have edited my answer @Amal. I don't know if it's correct or not, but if you can provide your desired output for your example input it will help determine whether or not I've understood the problem